# Что будет в регистре al и почему?

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Есть код, не понимаю что выйдет в конце. Что будет в регистре al и почему?

```
mov    al,100    ;al = 100
mov    bl,16     ;bl = 16
shl    al, 1     ;al = 101
sub    al,bl     ;al=al-bl    al=101-16=85
xor    al,bl
```

Comment: `shl    al, 1` это сдвиг регистра al на один бит влево, а не сложение. После выполнения этой операции в регистре будет 200. потом делайте вычитание, записывайте результат в двоичном виде и смотрите что сделает с битами xor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shl al,1` в регистре было 100 `(0110 0100b)`, команда сдвигает значение регистра на 1 бит влево, соответственно `al = 200 (1100 1000b)`. Думаю, с командой `sub al,bl` понятно, `al = 184`. Для того чтобы понять как команда `xor al,bl` работает, посмотрим на таблицу истинности исключающего ИЛИ (либо одно, либо другое, но не оба значения битов одинаковы):

```
0 | 0| 0
0 | 1| 1
1 | 0| 1
1 | 1| 0
```

Команда `xor` инвертирует одинаковые по значению биты. И раз `al = 184 (1011 1000b)`, а `bl = 16 (0001 0000b)`, то `al` становится равен `168 (1010 1000b)`, т.е. мы просто инвертировали 5ый бит в регистре `al`.